# Using v-show/v-if with Vue Formulate form schemas

Tags: vue.js, vue-formulate

Vue Formulate offers form schemas – a declarative way of defining the form fields you want and letting Vue Formulate take care of rendering it.

Currently for the complex forms I'm building, I'm using `v-show` directives to conditionally show/hide form fields depending on the inputs in other fields, e.g.:

```html
      <div v-show="formValues.primaryIncomeType == 'selfEmployed'">
        <formulate-input
          name="companyNumber"
          type="text"
          label="UK company number"
        ></formulate-input>
...
```

Is this something that's possible with form schemas? Have tried some variations on the following with no luck:

```js
  {
      component: "div",
      style: "display: flex",
      "v-show": "someCondition == true",
      children: [
        {
          type: "currency",
          name: "propertyValue",
          label: "Property value",
          validation: "required",
          validationName: "Property value"
        }
      ]
  }
```

Comment: see: https://github.com/wearebraid/vue-formulate/issues/230

Comment: Thanks @LawrenceCherone, hadn't spotted that!